# CSS Selectors with same second part

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have 2 selectors that can be itemID-XX and articleID-YY like this:

`.itemID-XX.articleID-YY`

The XX and YY are numbers that are generated dynamically by this script:

`<div class="itemID-<?php echo $item->id; ?> articleID-<?php echo $article_id; ?>">`

How can I say in CSS if XX=YY then add my declarations, or through PHP if XX=YY then add a new class, or maybe jQuery?

Thank you.

Comment: you cant do it in CSS if `XX` and `YY` are dynamic. If they are a known value, then css preprocessor like SCSS, LESS or Stylus might be able to help

Comment: ok I have this <div class="itemID-21 articleIID-33"> and numbers are dynamic, so if I have this <div class="itemID-21 articleIID-21"> I want to have a specific declaration

Comment: This sounds like the class names are generated dynamically, right? Can't you change the routine that generated them to also include a new class `thesame` if the numbers are the same?

Comment: Otherwise, if the numbers are all 2 digits, you could brute-force it. One hundred selectors is not that much work for a browser.

Comment: yes they are dynamic numbers from <?php echo $item->id; ?> and <?php echo $article_id; ?>"> any idea to compare and if the same to add thesame?

Comment: @geoplous If you sum up all your comments and edit them in to a new question, and also add `php` to the tag list, you'll get a better answer

Comment: ok I sum up an updated question

Comment: I edited my answer based on the new information. Please disregard the old version of the answer!

Comment: even better, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to add a new class if the numbers are the same.
Inside the routine that echoes the classes, add this:

```html
<div class="itemID-<?php echo $item->id; ?> articleID-<?php
 echo $article_id;
 if ($item->id==$article_id)
   echo " thesame";
?>">
```

and then you can simply use `.thesame` for a selector in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Answer is **No**

as with plain css we cant compare two classes you need js for that

If you want to select static selectors only then below code will work for you

```
[class*='XX'][class*='YY']{
   // code here
}
```

```css
/* if you want to target both */
[class*='XX'][class*='YY'] {
    color: red;
}

/*to target YY*/
[class*='YY']{
  color: green;
}

/*to target XX*/
[class*='XX']{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="itemID-XX articleID-YY">xx yy</p>
<p class="articleID-YY">yy</p>
<p class="itemID-XX">yy</p>
<p class="as-dsads-as">dsds</p>
```

Comment: Maybe my description is not so clear: I want declarations only if XX=YY, XX and YY are numbers

Comment: Oh.. then you will need js for that as in plain css we cant check that condition